# A graph of order $2n$ for which all vertices have degree $\geq n$ may be partitioned into adjacent pairs.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $G$ is a graph with $2n$ vertices for which every vertex has degree at least $n$. Prove that we can partition $V(G)$ into pairs such that the two vertices in each pair are adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

[Dirac's theorem](http://myweb.facstaff.wwu.edu/sarkara/dirac.pdf) gives us a Hamiltonian cycle $v_1v_2v_3\ldots v_{2n-1}v_{2n}v_1$, so $$\left\{\left(v_i,v_{i+1}\right):i=1,\ldots,2n-1\right\}$$
is one such set of pairs.